# Longest substring in Kdb

Tags: kdb

I am looking for a solution to this in kdb:
https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-substring-without-repeating-characters/description/
Not sure of an efficient way to write this.

One further question - is there a way to get scan to stop if a certain condition is met?
Just as an example, say I am running a function that builds the Fibonacci sequence:
`8{x,sum -2#x}\1 1`

Instead of specifying do 8 times, how can I stop it once the sum of the entire list is more than 100?

Thanks!

Comment: What have your tried so far to find the longest substring? Note that you should include the problem in your question as context will be lost if the link goes down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the Fibonacci sequence with a limit you can use this to stop once the sum exceeds 100:

```
{x,sum -2#x}\[{x>sum y}100;1 1]
```

See [documentation](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/accumulators/#while).

I'm sure there are better ways to do it but this should find the length of the max substring.

```
f:{[d;s]
  / find next substrings and discard those with duplicates
  nd:enlist[count s] _ (key[d] where not in'[l;get d])#d,'l:s key d;
  / if no results then max has been reached
  $[0=count nd;(d;s);(nd;1_s)]
 }

maxSubstring:{if[x~distinct x;:count x]; count first @[;0](f .)/[(-1_til[count x]!x;1_x)]};
```